# If $i$ is the identity mapping on $S$, prove that for any $\sigma\in A(S), \sigma\circ i=i\circ\sigma=\sigma$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$S$ is a set, $A(S)$ is the set of all automorphism, and $\sigma$ are maps in $A(S)$. I tried showing $\sigma i=\sigma$, can someone tell me if this is correct.

Because $A(S)$ is the set of automorphisms, $\sigma:S\to S$. We want to show that $\forall s\in S,\sigma\circ i$ and $\sigma$ map to the same thing.

Suppose $s\in S$ and we apply the map $\sigma\circ i$. Reading from right to left, this would look like: $\sigma\circ i(s)$. By defining of the identity map, any element plugged into $i$ will be outputted the same, i.e. $i(s)=s$. This gives $\sigma (s)$; thus $\sigma i=\sigma$.

Comment: Did you mean "We want to show that ∀"*sigma* (not s), ∈S,σ∘i
 and σ  map to the same thing.

Comment: Both $\sigma$ and $\sigma i$ are maps from $S$ to $S$, @nickalh.

Comment: That doesn't address my question.  However, I realized Musical Taco is right the first time.  s is an element in S.  $\sigma$ is a function or mapping S to S, $\sigma (s)$ would go to say $s' \in S$  I just needed to read it a bit more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. And likewise $(i\sigma)(s)=$ $i(\sigma(s))=$ $\sigma(s)$ for every $s\in S$, whence $i\sigma=\sigma$. In this all you haven't used anything more than the definition of the identity map of $S$ and $\sigma$ being a map from $S$ to $S$. Being an automorphism (or even just a bijection) is then over-determined here. Perhaps you need that for other properties of $A(S)$, out of the scope of this post.